# Qemu not responding after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, qemu, macos-catalina

After upgrading my Mac to Catalina, I can't use qemu anymore. Whenever I try to start it, it just hangs. The menu bar also doesn't respond while the qemu window is active.
Running `qemu-system-i386 --help` does work though.

Qemu version: 4.1.0

Edit: Passing `-nographic` fixes the issue.

Comment: Run into the same thing just now, `-vnc :0` can be used for now. Probably some awesome security feature or on Apple's side to work around...

Comment: This sounds like the same thing people are reporting in https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1847906 . (As a practical matter, this is unlikely to be fixed for a while unless somebody who actually has Catalina cares to investigate and submit a patch.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of a change in behaviour in Catalina which breaks an assumption in the design of the QEMU Cocoa front-end. We've put in a change to the QEMU code (upstream git commit dff742ad27efa474) which avoids the hang; this will be in the upcoming QEMU 4.2 release. In the meantime a workaround is to avoid the Cocoa frontend (eg using -nographic to turn off graphics altogether, or using one of the other display frontends like VNC or Spice).

(The technical detail of the Catalina behaviour change is that NSApplicationDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching documents that it is called before any events are processed [ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428385-applicationdidfinishlaunching ] and this was true in older versions of OSX, but in Catalina at least one event is sent to the app before applicationDidFinishLaunching, which triggered a deadlock in QEMU.)

A feedback report has apparently been filed with Apple about the OSX behaviour change, bug number FB7380815.

Answer (score 0):

Get SDL

```
 brew install sdl2
```

and the Qemu sources

```
git clone https://git.qemu.org/git/qemu.git
```

then configure using

```
./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu,x86_64-softmmu --enable-sdl --disable-cocoa --enable-sdl-image
```

then

```
make & make install
```

This deploys useable qemu binaries that use SDL instead of cocoa.
Good luck!

Comment: `make install` would end with: `/bin/sh: msgfmt: command not found` ; I fixed with: `brew install gettext ; brew link --force gettext`, then `make install` worked.

Comment: `ERROR: User requested feature sdl_image
       configure was not able to find it.
       Install SDL Image devel`  fixed with `brew install sdl2_image`