# AVD Crashing qemu-system-i386 quit unexpectedly after MacOS Catalina Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, macos-catalina

I have been running Android Studio on my Macbook for over a year perfectly fine. Recently I decided to upgrade to MacOS Catalina. The upgrade went successfully, but when I ran Android Studio again, I've been receiving this error constantly when I try to start a virtual device. Tried cold boot, wiping virtual device data, cloning virtual device, creating a fresh new device,
Even tried this as a solution (found it on the internet).

**`sudo launchctl remove com.cylance.agent_service`**

But nothing seems to works. Here's a screenshot of the error[image: AVD Error Message]

Comment: try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318920/qemu-not-responding-after-upgrading-to-macos-catalina][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to the weird problem. So apparently Android Studio Emulator works in a weird way. I have a dual monitor setup, so I had opened the emulator on monitor 1 and closed it on monitor 2 and then was trying to reopen on monitor 2. What the emulator does is it leaves some files behind from monitor 1 behind that interfere when it is restarted on monitor 2. So I re-opened it on monitor 1 and it worked. Saw this on some youtube video, didn't believe it'd work, but it did and I forgot I had asked it here as no one replied and I got busy. Now that I know I would like to leave it here, in case someone else has the same issue.